# Jenkins - Is there a way to parse console output and set environment variable

Tags: jenkins

I am relatively new to Jenkins. I am into a scenario where I need to read the console output and find a specific string and set this as environment variable. This variable I would be using in some downstream jobs.

for example: my jenkins job's console would contain something like

`product_build_number: 123456`

I have looked into FindText, log parser like plugins but they don't help me in setting this value as environment variable

Can somebody help in finding this number and pass it to downstream jobs?

**

> Updated with Answer:

**

```
def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*product_build_number=(\\d+.*)")
if(matcher.matches()) {
    pbn= matcher.group(1).substring(0)
    manager.build.setDescription(pbn) // you can do anything with this here
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way you can get this number (via the console)? Can you get a hold of the build number in any other way? (Reading a property file, querying a service)?

Comment: this number is output of some other script which gets executed during my job. and I have no control over this script

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

Example:

> The script below puts a warning badge and mark the build as unstable if it detects that deprecated methods were used.

```
if(manager.logContains(".*uses or overrides a deprecated API.*")) {
    manager.addWarningBadge("Thou shalt not use deprecated methods.")
    manager.createSummary("warning.gif").appendText("<h1>You have been warned!</h1>", false, false, false, "red")
    manager.buildUnstable()
}
```

### Solution

Complete solutions uses not only [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to parse console output and to set variable `BUILD_MSG`, but also needs [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to trigger downstream job with predefined parameter `MSG=${BUILD_MSG}`. Downstream job automatically has access to `MSG` parameter.

Groovy Postbuild script:

```
import hudson.model.*


matcher = manager.getLogMatcher('^build msg: (.*)$')

if (matcher.matches()) {
    buildMsg=matcher.group(1)

    manager.build.addAction(
        new ParametersAction([
            new StringParameterValue("BUILD_MSG", "${buildMsg}")
        ])
    )
}
```

Comment: I will try and let you know in a while

Comment: Cool, I had to remove the "[]" from the ParametersAction and to add System.setProperty("hudson.model.ParametersAction.safeParameters", "BUILD_MSG") or to the starting of jenkins-Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.safeParameters=BUILD_MSG to make it work.