# Extract text from Current Jenkins Console Log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a requirement where in the last stage of the pipeline I need to check the Jenkins console log of that build for something like below.
And get that into a variable as I have to pass that to something else.

```
----------Test Result----------
<Test 1>: Result 1
<Test 2>: Result 2
...
<Test n>: Result n
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Hope this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420157/jenkins-is-there-a-way-to-parse-console-output-and-set-environment-variable You can find the answer inline with question.

Comment: In a similar situation we write the needed text into a file. We use `pytest` so we wrote code that is invoked when `pytest` has the results, and is passed the results.